# Given the equations $y=3\sin x+2$ and $y=x+c$, which statements are true?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> $y=3\sin x+2$
>
> $y=x+c$ where c is a constant
>
> Which of the following statements is/are true?
>
> 1. For some value of c: there is exactly one solution with $0\leq x\leq \pi$ and there is at least one solution with $-\pi< x<0$
> 2. For some value of c: there is exactly one solution with $0\leq x\leq \pi$ and there are no solutions with $-\pi< x<0$
> 3. For some value of c: there is exactly one solution with $0\leq x\leq \pi$ and there are no solutions with $x>\pi$

And why?

I tried solving it by picking values of x and seeing if they fit the statements.

Comment: Just draw the graphs of functions $f(x) = 3\sin x + 2$ and $g(x) = x + c$. Study what happens when you  change $c$.

Comment: Do you mean to draw them using a graphic calculator or by hand? Because I need to solve the problem without using a calculator

Comment: Draw by hand. They are quite simple to draw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you graph the functions (should be easy to do by hand. If you don't know how to graph the sine function, learn [here](https://www.purplemath.com/modules/grphtrig.htm)), a solution is where the graphs intersect.

Where c = 0:

[image: y=x and y=3sinx+2, intersects at one point between 0 and pi]

There is one solution between 0 and $\pi$. This proves option 3 and option 2 correct.

Where c = 1:

[image: y=x+1 and y=3sinx+2, intersects at one point between 0 and pi and 2 points between -pi and 0]

There are 3 solutions, two between $-\pi$ and 0 and one between 0 and $\pi$. This proves option 1 to be correct.

There you have it, all of the options are correct for the given functions.

Comment: Thank you very much!!